# Как правильно округлить число в sql?

Tags: sql, алгоритм

Есть данные следующего вида. Надо их округлить до ближайшей 5 или 0, т.е, из 357.3 должно получиться 360, из 16.9 - 15, из 233.9 - 235 и т.д. Никак не могу придумать, как это сделать средствами `sql`. Придумал только делить числа на 10, округлять и умножать на 10, но это работает только в большую сторону.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так подойдет?

```
ROUND(value, -1)
```

можно конечно в лоб

```
ROUND(value / 10) * 10
```

но вроде и первый способ должен сработать, а он всё таки более правильный ибо встроенный функционал

Чтобы не получить ошибку:

> [42883] ОШИБКА: функция round(double precision, integer) не существует
> Подсказка: Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена.
> Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов. Позиция: 8

надо явно преобразовать тип:

```
select round((v::Decimal),-2) as v from test;
```

Ответ нашел тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731907/error-function-rounddouble-precision-integer-does-not-exist

Comment: `[42883] ОШИБКА: функция round(double precision, integer) не существует Подсказка: Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов. Позиция: 8`. Из-за чего эта ошибка? Ну и я так понимаю, что значение по типу `353.3` будет к 350, а не к 355 округлено

Comment: тогда так - какая БД у вас или покажите весь запрос?

Comment: `postgresql` вот запрос `select round(width, -1) as width, depth as depth, height as heigth
from test_table`

Comment: странно, функция есть - второй способ работает?

Comment: Работает, если ставлю просто число в функцию, а не значение из таблицы

Comment: "The round function can be used in the following versions of PostgreSQL: PostgreSQL 9.4, PostgreSQL 9.3, PostgreSQL 9.2, PostgreSQL 9.1, PostgreSQL 9.0, PostgreSQL 8.4", а у вас какая версия?

Comment: у меня 14 версия

Comment: странно, в online редакторе попробовал код `create table test(v float); insert into test (v) values (1234.567); select round(v / 10) * 10 as v from test; ` - корректно округлил до десятков

Comment: все, решил вашу проблему - сейчас описание дополню свое

Comment: да, ошибки больше нет, но полагаю, что это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Ведь до ближайшей 5 этот способ не округляет

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Неужели не додумался до очевидного `round(v / 5) * 5 as v`?

Comment: умножаете на 2 округляете и делите на 2 - вроде будет тогда до 5 дотягивать

Comment: @Akina очевидное `round(v / 5) * 5 as v` действительно вернет из 227 - 225, к примеру. Но так же и из 228 получится 225

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Ты б хоть попробовал, прежде чем ерунду-то говорить... https://dbfiddle.uk/ULEtQqjz

Comment: @Akina https://imgur.com/a/ikzCyOI

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Может, мы хоть сейчас увидим наконец сведения о том, какая СУБД и какой версии используется? А то есть у меня подозрения, что деление внутри скобок выполняется целочисленное.. и надо его принудительно превращать в деление с плавающей точкой, скажем, путём `round(v / 5.0) * 5 as v`.

Comment: @Akina да, вы были правы, спасибо!